# how can i implement inverted index on numbers

Tags: python, bioinformatics, information-retrieval, inverted-index

I am new to python. I have a csv file having GCF_NO as column heading and WP_NO as values. I need to use this file and make a inverted index using python. Please guide

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odYSE.png)

Comment: That's not how this service works, sorry. You post your attempt, people tell you what's wrong with it / help to improve it. Not you post your homework, people solve it for you.

Comment: I agree with @Gameplay. You need to try solving it and post a attempt anyway more information is needed like does the column contain unique rows and what is the pattern of the text in the column before creating a method for sorting it